# TeamCity - Testing some endpoints and processing the results. Stuck with processing the result, how to send it from TC to visualisation

Tags: bash, teamcity, powerbi

I need to test some endpoint, send some dummy request and check the response. I am learning with TC so I thought I will try it there (not sure if it was a wise choice)

I have a build step with curl, using a parameter to pass the dummy request. Using sed to parse part of the results.

But now I am not sure how to move forward. The idea is to have some dashboard with a list of endpoints and last result and some statistic over last X calls etc. I was thinking about using PowerBI.

So not sure if I should now push results to GIT and process the result from GIT?  Or how to move forward.

```
#take dummy request from parameter
echo '%data%' > data.xml

#try curl of my endpoint 
result=$(curl --silent  --request POST  -d "@data.xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" https://endpoint/ws)

#sed some part of response which i dont need 
result_code=$(echo $result | sed 's;.*<result>;;1' | sed  's;</result>.*$;;1' )


#print result
echo $result_code
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please ?

Comment: if you want to have a test report you need to use any build tool like maven, gradle,... and use unit tests. those tools produce reports then TC will catch them and you'll be able to see some statistics

Comment: @xiawi I added code of build step

Comment: @daggett I never try test report in TC, I thought this would be easier, but I will check it. thank for the tip